# Can I setup a WAMP Virtual Machine on my guest OS that uses files from my Windows host?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, virtualization, wamp

I'm on a desktop PC, so I dont need Apache, MYSQL, PHP to run all the time on my main PC. Also I have all the good tools (adobe cs4, etc) on my XP box and they wont run on my Win2000 VM Guest, plus they would require another license even if they did. I'm not sure if its worth the trouble but figured I'd ask before I try to figure out how to attempt it.

Answer (score 1):

Share the folders from the host OS on the network.

Map them to drive letters on the guest OS.

Configure WAMP to use those drives.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set up shared directories which should fit for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but at work we have network shares and I can access the files on the network shares when I map to them. That may be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is to install XAMPP: http://www.apachefriends.org/es/xampp.html

In this way you can run it whenever you really need to.